# AppFabric Caching adding large object to a remote server

Tags: c#, wcf, caching, appfabric

I'm using AppFabric caching for Windows Server 1.1.  I'm trying to add an object of 80MB to the cache which is located on another server on the network.  I get the following error:

> ErrorCode:SubStatus:There is a temporary failure.
>   Please retry            later. (One or more specified cache servers
>   are unavailable, which could be caused by busy network or servers. For
>   on-premises cache clusters, also verify the following conditions.
>   Ensure that security permission has been granted for this client
>   account, and check that the AppFabric Caching Service is allowed
>   through the firewall on all cache hosts. Also the MaxBufferSize on the
>   server must be greater than or equal to the serialized object size
>   sent from the client.): inner
>   System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: The socket was aborted
>   because an asynchronous receive from the socket did not complete
>   within the allotted timeout of 00:01:00. The time allotted to this
>   operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout. --->
>   System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An established connection was
>   aborted by the software in your host machine    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.Write(Byte[] buffer,
>   Int32 offset, Int32 size, Boolean immediate, TimeSpan timeout)    ---
>   End of inner exception stack trace ---    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.Write(Byte[] buffer,
>   Int32 offset, Int32 size, Boolean immediate, TimeSpan timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.Write(Byte[] buffer,
>   Int32 offset, Int32 size, Boolean immediate, TimeSpan timeout,
>   BufferManager bufferManager)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.BufferedConnection.WriteNow(Byte[]
>   buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, TimeSpan timeout, BufferManager
>   bufferManager)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.BufferedConnection.Write(Byte[] buffer,
>   Int32 offset, Int32 size, Boolean immediate, TimeSpan timeout,
>   BufferManager bufferManager)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.FramingDuplexSessionChannel.OnSend(Message
>   message, TimeSpan timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.OutputChannel.Send(Message message,
>   TimeSpan timeout)    at
>   Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.WcfClientChannel.SendOnChannel(EndpointID
>   endpoint, TimeSpan& timeout, WaitCallback callback, Object state,
>   Boolean async,   IDuplexSessionChannel channel, Message message)

I can add smaller objects fine to the remote server so it's obviously something to do with the size. I've also installed the Cumulative update package 3 for AppFabric. I've disabled all security. Any ideas?

Server Config File:

```
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="dataCache" type="Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.DataCacheSection, Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.Core, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    </configSections>
    <dataCache size="Small">
        <caches partitionCount="32">
            <cache consistency="StrongConsistency" name="default" minSecondaries="0">
                <policy>
                    <eviction type="Lru" />
                    <expiration defaultTTL="1440" isExpirable="true" />
                </policy>
            </cache>
        </caches>
        <hosts>
            <host replicationPort="22236" arbitrationPort="22235" clusterPort="22234"
                hostId="1216617116" size="6126" leadHost="true" account="test$"
                cacheHostName="AppFabricCachingService" name="test.com"
                cachePort="22233" />
        </hosts>
        <advancedProperties>
            <securityProperties mode="None" protectionLevel="None">
                <authorization>
                    <allow users="IIS AppPool\test" />
                </authorization>
            </securityProperties>
            <transportProperties maxBufferPoolSize="26843545600" maxBufferSize="838860800" receiveTimeout="40000" />
        </advancedProperties>
        <deploymentSettings>
            <deploymentMode value="RoutingClient" />
        </deploymentSettings>
    </dataCache>
</configuration>
```

Section from Web.config from Client which is trying to push to AppFabric:

```
<dataCacheClient requestTimeout="60000" channelOpenTimeout="12000" maxConnectionsToServer="1">
    <localCache isEnabled="false" sync="TimeoutBased" ttlValue="300" objectCount="10000"/>
    <clientNotification pollInterval="300" maxQueueLength="10000"/>        
    <securityProperties mode="None" protectionLevel="None" />
    <transportProperties connectionBufferSize="131072" maxBufferPoolSize="568435456" maxBufferSize="183886080" maxOutputDelay="2" channelInitializationTimeout="60000" receiveTimeout="60000" />  </dataCacheClient>
```

The connection is established in code as follows:

```
DataCacheServerEndpoint[] servers = new DataCacheServerEndpoint[1];
                servers[0] = new DataCacheServerEndpoint("remoteServerName", 22233);

                DataCacheFactoryConfiguration factoryConfig = new DataCacheFactoryConfiguration();
                factoryConfig.Servers = servers;

                //Pass configuration settings to cacheFactory constructor
                _factory = new DataCacheFactory(factoryConfig);

                _cache = _factory.GetCache("default");
```

And finally the code to add an item to the cache:

```
_cache.CreateRegion(region);                             
_cache.Put(key, value, new TimeSpan(0, timeToLive, 0), tag, region);
```

Comment: Add your server and client config files(change server names if need be before posting)and we can attempt to help

Comment: Question updated with relevant config files

Comment: try align your client and server config files. maxBufferPoolSize and maxBufferSize should be the same on the client and server.

Comment: I'll try that now and let you know if it helps.

Comment: Unfortunately the same error occurs after aligning the values

Comment: One more point, when I try to add the same object to a local cache it works fine.

Comment: Firewall permissions?  Proxy? Upload MB limit? Three things I can suggest looking into-otherwise I cant see anything wrong.

Comment: I've had the firewall turned off and there's no proxy in play. I can't see how there would be an upload limit set anywhere on the network. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to this issue was to increase the requestTimeout in the client web.config and remove the receiveTimeout setting.

The web.config now looks like:

```
<dataCacheClient requestTimeout="600000" channelOpenTimeout="12000" maxConnectionsToServer="1">
    <localCache isEnabled="false" sync="TimeoutBased" ttlValue="300" objectCount="10000"/>
    <clientNotification pollInterval="300" maxQueueLength="10000"/>        
    <securityProperties mode="None" protectionLevel="None" />
    <transportProperties connectionBufferSize="131072" maxBufferPoolSize="568435456" maxBufferSize="183886080" maxOutputDelay="2" channelInitializationTimeout="60000" />  </dataCacheClient>
```